# Unable to run WebLogic Server in debug mode in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic-10.x

I am not trying to do any remote debugging in Eclipse. I am just trying to run WebLogic Server (which is in Eclipse) in `DEBUG` mode. I am getting a strange error message, which is shown in the attached image. The server is not starting from Eclipse when I try after this option. I am using Java 1.6

[image]

Comment: Is there any anti virus/firewall running in your system ?...can you disable and check it again ?

Comment: I cannot change the settings of the firewall, as we are restricted to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do below setting to start debugger, it works fine in my case:

1. Edit /bin/setDomainEnv.sh file and add this on top:

   JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y"

   The suspend=y will start your server and wait for you to connect with IDE before continue. 
   If you don't want this, then set to suspend=n instead.
2. Start/restart your WLS with /bin/startWebLogic.sh
3. Once WLS is running, you may connect to it using Eclipse IDE. 
   Go to Menu: Run > Debug Configuration ... > Remote Java Application and create a new entry. 
   Ensure your port number is matching to what you used above.